# Conditional formatting based on number and symbol

Tags: excel, formatting, conditional-statements, formula

This is an odd question. I have an issue I need to highlight a cell based on value, but it has a symbol in it and I cNt remove the symbol.

Value ranges are 1+   3+    5+  etc..

Need to highlight  for each series  higher than 1 but less than 3.   Higher than 3 but less than 7.   Etc...

Hope that makes sense. 
Thanks 
Casey

Comment: Doesn't make sense to me. Can you please include sample data and sample desired output? Not sure what you mean by symbol.

Comment: Why don't you remove the symbol and use a custom number format of `0+` ?

Comment: Manager wants to use the 3+ style  basically its a tool where based on experience what jobs you will be qualified for so if you have 3+ experience then you apply... So we have multiple jobs requirements are 3+ 5+ 10+ etc... And we have a drop down where it has 1+ etc.. So the user picks a drop-down and they want to highlight other cells that are within the experience ranges so user highlights 5+  they want all the 3+ sections highlighted as well.      Sorry symbol is the +

Comment: I thought about making a table of some kind to reference values associated with the 3+... Etc instead of the using conditional formatting equation input value less than or equal but the + throws it of it only highlights the =.

Comment: I'm very new to vba fyi etc..just started making if then loops etc....

Comment: Thank you Jeeped - I see what you mean.  Looks like they decided to revamp it in a different direction, but I do see how that could work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should still be able to evaluate the number with the symbol after it, Excel should treat it as text where 1+ is still less than 3+ or 5+ is greather than 3+.

In your conditional formatting the rule would look something like this;

```
Cell Value <= $D$1
```

Where `$D$1` is your selectable list which i'm assuming is possibly a validation list.

The format for the condition is whichever color you want it to highlight, and the `Applies to` part of the condition would be the range that you want to check against i.e. `=$A:$A` where all the 1+,3+,5+ numbers are.

This doesn't get you the whole answer but it should point you in the direction of setting your conditional formats.